# Mapping of streams, should I mutate the main stream?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Inside service I get data from server and push it to streams:

```
public rights$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
public users$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);

.subscribe((res => {
    this.rights$.next(res.rights);
    this.users$.next(res.users);
});
```

I do this to share initial data in some places of application. But in one place I need to map `this.users$` to `UserUI` type:

```
interface UserUI {
   checked: boolean;
   date: Date
}
```

Should I create a new stream like in the same service core?

```
public users$ = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>([]);
public usersUI$ = new BehaviorSubject<UserUI[]>([]);
```

Mapping:

```
this.usersUI$ = this.users$.pipe(map((users: User[]) => users.map((user: User) => {..user, checked: true, date: new Date})
```

Or better to make mapping in place where I need `this.usersUI$`?
What is the best practice?

Answer (score 2):

its kind of duplication and it affects performance, you will have to deal with 2 observables instead of one where you don't need that at all, means more code, more test to write.

I suggest that you keep only one **users$**, and where you need adapt it you can do it on your component level
So create shared adapter

```
userAdapter(user: User): UserUI {
 return {...user, checked: true, date: new Date}
}
```

and depends on needs in your component

```
const usersUI = service.users$.pipe( 
 map((users: User[]) => users.map(u => userAdapter(u)))
)
```